# ListView with a dynamic intents that change a TextView and WebView on each call

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-intent

**Activity that is sending the putExtra()**

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    final Intent intent = new Intent();
    // Set up different intents based on the item clicked: 
    switch (position)
    {
        case ACTIVITY_0:
            intent.putExtra("Value1", "Display this text!");
            intent.setClass(this, com.a.someclass.class);
}
    startActivityForResult(intent, position);
}
```

**Activity receiving the putExtra()**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.information);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras == null) {
        return;
    }
    String value1 = extras.getString("Value1");

    if (value1 != null) {
        informationTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.informationTitle);
        informationText = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.informationText);
        informationTitle.setText(value1);
    }
```

**Original Message:**

i have been searching everywhere for a good tutorial on this, i have posted my code online so people can look at it but have not found the help i needed.

I am new to this and what i am basically trying to do is just have a list of items which are all linked to one class that has a dynamic TextView that will be used for the title and a WebView for content,  And so basically when a item is clicked on the list it will open up the new activity/intent and it will also pass arguments to change the TextView and WebView accordingly.

I know how to open a new activity by making a new class for each item on the list but i am pretty sure there is an easier way where i can reuse one class and just keep changing the TextView and WebView.  The reason i say this is because i have 15 items on my list, but that will expand overtime so i dont want to be making 50-60 different classes to open up each new item.

If some could point me to the right tutorial or give me some insight on here i will really really appreciate it!

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish that, you would, instead of using a different `Intent` for each list item, call the same `Activity` with the same `Intent`, but pass extras along with it.

Let's say, for instance, that you want to pass a different `String` depending on which list item is clicked.  You would want to

```
myIntent.putExtra(String key, String value);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

The `Activity` that you start with this `Intent` will then be able to grab these extras in its `onCreate()` using

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
```

and access the extras you put in the `Intent` using the methods outlined [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html).  This way you can use a single `Activity` for all list items but have the `Activity` display different information based on the extra values.

Comment: I have not been able to get this to work, when i try to change a textview it tell me to change the putExtra class to something else.

Comment: The putExtra "class?"  Editing your original question with your updated code would help give me an idea of what you're talking about.

Comment: well, is putExtra only used to change strings? because i dont see that it offers to change any other type of parameter other than string.

Comment: It's not used to "change" anything.  It's used to pass information to the `Activity` described in the `Intent`.  Whether or not you use the information in the next `Activity` is up to you.  And if you go to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html you'll see that there are 20+ different `putExtra()` methods for passing information from primitive types to `Serializable` objects.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much, im actually getting A LOT closer to what i wanna do, i can actually get it to where if i set a value and put some text it will pass that text to the next activity and display it but i was wondering if there is a way to pass in a string value from strings.xml, because for the webview i will need to pass in the file location to the page i want the webview to display.  I have updated the original message to show the code i have that is working for me.

Comment: To get a `String` from your strings.xml file, you just use `getString(R.string.string_name)`.  You can either use the information from `Value1` to determine which `String` to grab in the second `Activity` or set another extra in your first `Activity` with the `String` resource in it.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help, i have a better understanding of whats going on and i was actually able to finish a part of my app, everything else is just external content that i have to make!  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you a link where you can get the best tutorial for that...
http://www.vogella.de/articles/Android/article.html