# How to go from a selected button in a list to different activities or the same activity with different text

Tags: android

So, I'm making my first android app and want to perform a simple task, but can't seem to figure out the way to do it. I simply want to go from a list view to a screen of differing information based on which button was pressed.  The information is similar enough(ie. a title and block of text) that I think I can use the same activity for it all, but I don't know how to switch out the different information based on the user's selection. Should I make a separate activity for each button in the list, or can I have the first activity send context to a single next activity and somehow determine what xml code to use, and how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555241/listview-with-a-dynamic-intents-that-change-a-textview-and-webview-on-each-call/6555290#6555290).  The original question in that thread also now contains an example of some code that appears to work.

Comment: Thanks! I really did try to find a similar question, my bad...